# Gas estimation failed when trying to get flashloan from Multiplier (on bsc)

Tags: solidity, bsc, flash-loans

I get a pop-up window every time when calling flashloan function says

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
> transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Internal JSON-RPC error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./base/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import "./interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "./interfaces/ILendingPool.sol";
import "./interfaces/IDefi.sol";


contract FlashLoanDemo is FlashLoanReceiverBase {

    address public constant BNB_ADDRESS = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;

    constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressesProvider)
        public
        FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressesProvider)
    {
    }

    function flashloanBnb(uint256 _amount) public {
        bytes memory data = "";
       
        ILendingPool lendingPool = ILendingPool(
            addressesProvider.getLendingPool()
        );
        lendingPool.flashLoan(address(this), BNB_ADDRESS, _amount, data);
    }
    
}
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Which provider do you use for the flashloan?

Comment: I use Testnet LendingPoolAddressProvider from this document https://mcl-docs.multiplier.finance/developers/testnet-addresses.

Comment: Did you implement executeOperation as indicated i their documentation? https://mcl-docs.multiplier.finance/developers/api-reference/flash-loans

Comment: Yes, I get the code from its Github page. [link] https://github.com/Multiplier-Finance/MCL-FlashloanDemo/tree/main/contracts[link]  Can you tell me why it shows the error (Gas estimation failed)

Comment: Usually the error means there's a bug in the contracts.